# Visual Studio project settings to instrument for Intel Trace Analyzer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mpi, hpc

I'm just getting started with Intel MPI and am trying to understand how to use Trace Analyzer. My understanding is that linking with vt.lib and running an mpi application is sufficient to cause a *.stf file to be emitted. I have a simple Hello World MPI application. After linking with vt.lib and running through mpiexec, I see no stf output.

There's not much more information to add. The setup could not be simpler. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get STF results. Here's what I did:

- vt.lib must be before impi.lib in the link line.
- I had to include vt.h and invoke VT_initialize, VT_traceon, and VT_finalize.

I don't know why these steps are necessary. I found no documentation to suggest they are, and I figured this out through slow trial-and-error.